# Unable to ssh into private subnet using Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-vpc

I have setup a VPC with 2 subnets. One of them is public other one is private.

I am able to ssh from an instance in public subnet to an instance in private subnet using the private IP address of machine. However, if I use the elastic IP address of private instance, the connection times out.

For example, lets call EC2 instance in public subnet as "PUB" and instance in private subnet as PRV.

PRV has Elastic IP say "EIP" and private address, say PRV_IP.

When I ssh from public instance to private one using the private IP address, connection is successful, however if I use private IP, connection fails.

That is,
ssh -i private_key ec2-user@EIP (succeeds).

ssh -i private_key ec2-user@PRV_IP (fails, connection timesout).

Can someone explain me why connection is failing with elastic IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have seen, attaching Elastic IPs to an instance in private subnet is a worthless exercise. This happens because each subnet can have exactly one default route and that will either point to the *igw* object (public subnet) or the *NAT* instance/gateway(private subnet).

If you are binding an elastic IP to a machine in the private subnet, the inbound traffic would arrive at the instance, but the outbound reply traffic would be routed back through the NAT instance, which would discard it.

That's why when you are trying to do SSH, your client machine is able to send a request to the instance but the instance is not returning back the response, hence the timeout.